# Value based on multiple MERGED DIMENSIONS

Tags: business-objects, webi

The VLOOKUP equivalent within business objects is to use a **merged dimension** then create a **detail object** using the merged dimension. Which works fine.

However, what if you want the value to be returned based on **multiple merged dimensions**? When creating a detail object it only gives you the option to select one.

e.g if I have 2 reports

**Report 1**

Employee ID

Name

**Report 2**

Employee ID

Age

I could do a merge on Employee ID, create a detail object using the merged dimension which returns Age.

However if i had 2 reports like this

**Report 1**

Employee ID

Position ID

Name

**Report 2**

Employee ID

Position ID

Age

And only want to return Age if the Employee ID and Position ID match. How would i go about this?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: What version of BusinessObjects are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to merge on variables was introduced in version [4.2 SP3](https://infosolblog.com/tech-tip-merging-on-variables-in-web-intelligence/). So if you are on that version or higher you can concatenate your **Employee ID** and **Position ID** from each data source like this.

```
Report1 Employee ID~PositionID=[Report1 Employee ID] + "~" + [Report1 Position ID]
Report2 Employee ID~PositionID=[Report2 Employee ID] + "~" + [Report2 Position ID]
```

Then merge the resulting **Report1 Employee ID~PositionID** and **Report1 Employee ID~PositionID** variables.